# Difference between Docker and CS Docker Engine ?

Tags: docker

I want to know what is the difference between Open Source Docker and CS Commercial Supported Docker Engine .

I understand CS Docker engine is subscribed one 
but my question is the installation binary different for both versions ?

Comment: i believe installation binaries for both are different since for CS engine.. url to download binaries is https://sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xee6d536cf7dc86e2d7d56f59a178ac6c6238f52e

Comment: would you mind to add the answer from google groups here as own answer?